# ajax response 5000 table rows in array not loading in bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

i am using following function to get ajax data in response. working fine on reponse with 4000 items as items exceeded no data loading in table jquery error accours 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Not Allowed)
my ajax call is

```
$.ajax({
                beforeSend: function () {
                    AppLaunchAnimationStart();
                },
                complete: function () {
                    AppLaunchAnimationEnd();
                },
                url: url + "/GetDuplicates",
                method: "POST",
                data: {id:folderID, array1:checkedOptions, uncheckNodes:unCheckFolderID},
                dataType: "json",
                timeout: 0,
                success: function (data)
                {
```

Comment: [MDN 405](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405): The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 405 Method Not Allowed response status code indicates that the request method is known by the server but has been disabled and cannot be used.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about that. But i think you might need to increase the post_max_size in your php.ini file.

```
#set max post size
php_value post_max_size 20M
```